# Forcefully pushed files in Git and deleted all updated files in local repo

Tags: git, github, repository, push

I have forcefully pushed files to the remote repo and all updated files were deleted in my local repo. those pushed files visible are in the remote repo as committed files but I can't retrieve them at all.  what can I do to retrieve them?
thank you!

Comment: Have a look in the commit history on github. If you still have the version there that you want you to know how to lose your latest change. What I am concerned though, from your question, is the word "forced". If you had to force a push, that implies you have somehow lost commits on the github side. That makes things much harder - you would need to see if you perhaps had another clone somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

> those pushed files visible are in the remote repo as committed files but I can't retrieve them at all.

Start by cloning again your repository: you should get your files there.
If there are listed in a different branch, you can [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) to said branch.
If they are listed in a past commit, you can [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) them.